# How to set different context paths for web and webservice

Tags: servlets, contextroot

I have an application which contains both implementation of Webservices and WebApp and I am looking for an solution to set context path for both Webservices and WebApp differently

I would like to have:

localhost:8080/ws/* - webservice

localhost:8080/web/ - Webapp

My application is made with Spring MVC, JSF and the web services is made with Axis SOAP.

Comment: Just split into 2 WAR projects. Shared code can go into a JAR project which is then included in WEB-INF/lib of both WARs.

Comment: That´s a good idea that I was thinking but now it is no posible. Thanks BalusC